# How to call static methods from second project in the same solution?

Tags: c#, methods, call, project, solution

Could someone give me an advice on this question?
I need to call static method which is described in another project of the same solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Add the reference to the project and you will be able to call the class & its method

Comment: That's the point that I have reference! I can work with Class data of another project.

Comment: Then the problem is something outside of your description here, because if you have the reference to the project added, *it should work*.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click `Reference` from project you are working on(project to call the function) at solution explorer.
2. Click `Add Reference(R)`
3. Select `Project`(at left side) and add project to reference.

Comment: ...and give a look at the `Solution -> Properties -> Project Dependencies` & Co.

Comment: That's the point that I have reference! I can work with Class data of another project.